# Event Flow Filters Not Correctly Filtering Using Event Source As Input And ApplicationInsights as Output. Any ideas?

Tags: .net, azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-application-insights, event-flow

I am using event flow to send telemetry data to application insights in a service fabric application. The events seem to be created correctly but I seem to be encountering problems with the eventFlow filtering. When I try to filter my events as a exception or dependency they do not appear inside the application insights portal on Azure.

My logging events are created using eventSource.

Here is my output section from eventFlowConfig.json:

```
"outputs": [
    {
      "type": "ApplicationInsights",
      "instrumentationKey": "****************************************",
      "filters": [
        {
          "type": "metadata",
          "metadata": "exception",
          "include": "EventId == 10",
          "exceptionProperty": "operationType"
        }
      ]
```

Here are the versions of the packages I am using which are most relevant to this problem:

```
<package id="Microsoft.Diagnostics.EventFlow.Core" version="1.1.4" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Diagnostics.EventFlow.EtwUtilities" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Diagnostics.EventFlow.Inputs.EventSource" version="1.1.1" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Diagnostics.EventFlow.Outputs.ApplicationInsights" version="1.1.4" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Diagnostics.EventFlow.ServiceFabric" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" version="2.4.0-beta4" targetFramework="net46" />
```

Comment: What did you change in your code to generate the error event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, the exception property needs to contain an exception object, otherwise metadata decoration will fail. I do not think "operationType" property carries an exception, does it? See https://github.com/Azure/diagnostics-eventflow/issues/92 for some ideas on how to deal with this.

There is also an issue that if metadata decoration fails, the event just gets dropped by Application Insights output. This is tracked by https://github.com/Azure/diagnostics-eventflow/issues/95 We'll fix this soon.

Comment: Yes you are correct. Thanks for your insight! Yes I noticed that the event is getting when the property does not carry an exception.

Comment: I have a further small question you may be able to point me in the right direction with. I'm trying to use different eventFlow configurations across multiple environments and wish to use a different Application Insights instrumentationKey in each of these. I don't see any mention of this being possible in the Microsoft.Diagnostic.EventFlow Readme, do you know if this is currently supported and if so where I could find further information. Many thanks again!

Comment: If you use Service Fabric, EventFlow support reading configuration parameter values from Service Fabric settings and application parameters https://github.com/Azure/diagnostics-eventflow#support-for-service-fabric-settings-and-application-parameters   For other environments something similar could be added via Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration mechanisms (which EvenFlow uses under the covers)

Comment: @KarolZ where is the exception property? I read the following in the documentation but I don't know what `event property` it refers to. Documentation: The name of the event property that carries the (unexpected) exception object. Note that (for maximum information fidelity) the expected type of the event property is System.Exception. In other words, the actual exception is expected to be part of event data, and not just a stringified version of it.

Comment: @ErickB the exception property is the property of an event. 

For ApplicationInsights output to produce an Exception telemetry two things need to happen:
1. The event needs to have a property of type System.Exception (and that property needs to be initialized with valid Exception instance).
2. The event needs to have an exception metadata attached, telling the ApplicationInsights output where to "find" the System.Exception instance (i.e. which property to use).

Comment: Most logging libraries support #1 (for example: Microsoft.Extensions.Logging a.k.a. ILogger, Serilog, DiagnosticSource). You can also use Application Insights SDK directly. Notable logging API that puts restrictions on the types for event properties and DOES NOT support attaching instances of System.Exception to events is EventSource.